# Need help identifying a light switch

Tags: electrical, lighting, switch, home-automation, smart-switch

At work we have some light switches that look like this, and I've seen similar ones at school and at other commercial offices. This one is installed in Vancouver, Canada

The lights also have a motion detector installed elsewhere in the room that can turn them on and off.

I'm wondering what type of switch this is, and where I could get one. It looks like some form of low-voltage/networked lighting but none of the major manufacturers have it on their website.[image]

Comment: What country is this in?  Vastly different switches are used across the world.

Comment: This is in Vancouver, BC Canada. The other ones I've seen are also from here.

Comment: My guess is that it's some proprietary system that was sold 20+ years ago and doesn't follow any particular standard.  I'll let someone with more experience north of the 49th parallel answer, but that looks pretty custom to me.

Comment: The building was constructed in 2008, so I would think it's not TOOOO out of date.

Comment: Huh, ok.  That plastic looks aged like a 90's PC case so I assumed it was pretty old.  I guess you're not authorized to remove the switch cover and look for a brand name so that will make it harder.  The building maintenance staff might know if you can contact management.

Comment: @JPhi1618 Some companies actually *make it that color* :)

Answer (score 2):

### Dollars to donuts, this is an RR7 kind of deal

In this system, you have a **relay** back at the service panel or control cabinet.   You then run 24V low-voltage power to each switch and motion sensor.

The most common, the RR7, is a **latching relay**. If you send control power to the relay for 1 second, it "throws the relay over" and it stays there until it's thrown the other way.   Each bank of switches gets a 24V supply wire, and it returns an "on" wire and an "off" wire for each string of lights.  Energizing "on" for a moment throws the relay "on"; "off" does the same.

The neat thing about RR7 is you can have any number of switches controlling a light, and wire it with thermostat wire.  Also, you can have automated systems work very easily with it.  Say you want to turn off the lights at 8 pm, because people always forget to turn them off, the timer just pulses the "off" wire for 1 second at 8 pm.

### There are different systems

For instance one system has only one on/off wire, and energizing the wire for 1 second *toggles* the lights on vs. off.  That works for humans, but a machine (eg. The timer) needs a feedback wire to tell machines *if* the lights are already on or off, otherwise if they're off, the timer will *turn them on* at 8:00.  Anyway, that light may be this feedback wire.

These commercial systems are generally hard-wired old-school, because that is reliable and doesn't require a geek to troubleshoot balky software.